# JavaFX Tableview sort by custom rule, then by column selection

Tags: java, sorting, javafx

I am trying to sort a JavaFX `TableView` that contains 3 columns, one being a date, one being a name (string), and the last being the tags column (which is an enum). What I want to do is make it so that no matter which column the table is currently sorting on, the rows will *first* sort by the tags (where if it has a certain tag, it is ordered above rows that do not have that certain tag).

Thus when searching by name in ascending, the table will be order like so:

- 'George' [tag]
- 'ZZ' [tag]
- 'Apple' [no-tag]
- 'Hello' [no-tag]

etc.

I've looked at column comparators, however I can only seem to specify for that column type, ie I would like to be able to specify the name-column comparator to take in the whole row's class object, and the name-column datatype (string), so I can then access the tags within that class instance - however this doesn't seem to be possible after looking around online.

Would it also be possible to persist this rule even when the tags column is selected to order desc (so it still places rows with the tag first). If not I can just disable sorting for the tag column

Thanks in advance for anyone that can point me in the right direction

Comment: See the section about sorting [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html). One way to achieve what you describe is to create a `SortedList` as described, but rather than simply binding its comparator to that of the `TableView`, create a dependent one that first compares the tag value.

Comment: This would not work, because the SortedList requires its comparator to be bound to the TableView's comparator. So no custom comparator can be injected in between.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comment, you can't just create a binding, which wraps the comparator of the TableView and gives it to SortedList. Also SortedList is `final` so you can't extend it. Also using a custom `TransformationList` would not work, because the `TableView` has some hard coded stuff that starts with `if (itemsList instanceof SortedList)`. 
This is what I ended up with (using java7 format and not labdas for the sake of clarity):

```
    filteredList = new FilteredList<>(yourOriginalList);
    table.sortPolicyProperty().set(new Callback<TableView<YourObject>, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(TableView<YourObject> param) {
            final Comparator<YourObject> tableComparator = transactionTable.getComparator();
            // if the column is set to unsorted, tableComparator can be null
            Comparator<YourObject> comparator = tableComparator == null ? null : new Comparator<YourObject>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2) {
                    // first sort by your tag
                    final int tagCompare = o1.getTag().compareTo(o2.getTag());
                    if (tagCompare == 0) {
                        // secondly sort by the comparator that was set for the table
                        return tableComparator.compare(o1, o2);
                    }
                    return tagCompare;
                }
            };
            table.setItems(filteredList.sorted(comparator));
            return true;
        }
    });

    // you may also need to call
    table.setItems(filteredList.sorted(transactionTable.getComparator()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [@Miklos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1738827/miklos-jakab) solution. Below is a complete working example of your requirement (based on [@Miklos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1738827/miklos-jakab) solution) to sort first by Tag column before doing sort on the selected column. [This is not a full solution, but this should give you some direction to start with and make it working completly as per your needs]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import static javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING;

public class CustomComparatorTableColumn extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Device> devices = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        devices.add(new Device(1, "Apple", "Zebra", TagType.TAG));
        devices.add(new Device(2, "BlackBerry", "Parrot", TagType.TAG));
        devices.add(new Device(3, "Amazon", "Yak", TagType.NO_TAG));
        devices.add(new Device(4, "Oppo", "Penguin", TagType.NO_TAG));

        TableView<Device> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Device, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().nameProperty());

        TableColumn<Device, String> displayCol = new TableColumn<>("Display");
        displayCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().displayProperty());

        TableColumn<Device, TagType> tagCol = new TableColumn<>("Tag");
        tagCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().tagTypeProperty());

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, displayCol, tagCol);
        tableView.setItems(devices);

        tableView.setSortPolicy(tv -> {
            final ObservableList<Device> itemsList = tableView.getItems();
            if (itemsList == null || itemsList.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }
            final List<TableColumn<Device, ?>> sortOrder = new ArrayList<>(tableView.getSortOrder());
            if (!sortOrder.isEmpty()) {
                // If there is no Tag column in the sort order, always adding as the first sort to consider.
                if (!sortOrder.stream().anyMatch(tc -> tc.getText().equals("Tag"))) {
                    sortOrder.add(0, tagCol);
                }
                FXCollections.sort(itemsList, new TableColumnComparator<>(sortOrder));
            }
            return true;
        });

        Scene sc = new Scene(tableView);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    class TableColumnComparator<S> implements Comparator<S> {
        private final List<TableColumn<S, ?>> allColumns;

        public TableColumnComparator(final List<TableColumn<S, ?>> allColumns) {
            this.allColumns = allColumns;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(final S o1, final S o2) {
            for (final TableColumn<S, ?> tc : allColumns) {
                if (!isSortable(tc)) {
                    continue;
                }
                final Object value1 = tc.getCellData(o1);
                final Object value2 = tc.getCellData(o2);

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final Comparator<Object> c = (Comparator<Object>) tc.getComparator();
                final int result = ASCENDING.equals(tc.getSortType()) ? c.compare(value1, value2)
                        : c.compare(value2, value1);

                if (result != 0) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }

        private boolean isSortable(final TableColumn<S, ?> tc) {
            return tc.getSortType() != null && tc.isSortable();
        }
    }

    class Device {
        IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty display = new SimpleStringProperty();
        ObjectProperty<TagType> tagType = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public Device(int id, String n, String d, TagType tag) {
            this.id.set(id);
            name.set(n);
            tagType.set(tag);
            display.set(d);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public ObjectProperty<TagType> tagTypeProperty() {
            return tagType;
        }

        public StringProperty displayProperty() {
            return display;
        }

    }

    enum TagType {
        TAG, NO_TAG;
    }
}
```